# loading not showing within the box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used jquery and css to show a loader with gray background during an ajax call. The thing is I need the loader and the gray background to be visible only within a box like as shown below with loading text and icon in center

[image]

My code is working fine but the loader with gray background is showing for the full page like as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My code is as given below

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0zyc6ff/)

```
    ajaxindicatorstart('loading data.. please wait..');

    function ajaxindicatorstop()
    {
        $('#resultLoading .bg').height('100%');
        $('#resultLoading').fadeOut(300);
        $('.myBox').css('cursor', 'default');
    }

    function ajaxindicatorstart(text)
    {
        if($('.myBox').find('#resultLoading').attr('id') != 'resultLoading'){
            $('.myBox').append('<div id="resultLoading" style="display:none"><div><img src="http://w3lessons.info/demo/ajax-indicator/ajax-loader.gif"><div>'+text+'</div></div><div class="bg"></div></div>');
        }

        $('#resultLoading').css({
            'width':'100%',
            'height':'100%',
            'position':'fixed',
            'z-index':'10000000',
            'top':'0',
            'left':'0',
            'right':'0',
            'bottom':'0',
            'margin':'auto'
        });

        $('#resultLoading .bg').css({
            'background':'#000000',
            'opacity':'0.7',
            'width':'100%',
            'height':'100%',
            'position':'absolute',
            'top':'0'
        });

        $('#resultLoading>div:first').css({
            'width': '250px',
            'height':'75px',
            'text-align': 'center',
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top':'0',
            'left':'0',
            'right':'0',
            'bottom':'0',
            'margin':'auto',
            'font-size':'16px',
            'z-index':'10',
            'color':'#ffffff'

        });

        $('#resultLoading .bg').height('100%');
           $('#resultLoading').fadeIn(300);
        $('.myBox').css('cursor', 'wait');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loader has a position of `fixed`, this takes the position of the viewport rather than the position of your element.

```
    $('#resultLoading>div:first').css({
        'width': '250px',
        'height':'75px',
        'text-align': 'center',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top':'0',
        'left':'0',
        'right':'0',
        'bottom':'0',
        'margin':'auto',
        'font-size':'16px',
        'z-index':'10',
        'color':'#ffffff'

    });

    $('#resultLoading').css({
        'width':'100%',
        'height':'100%',
        'position':'absolute',
        'z-index':'10000000',
        'top':'0',
        'left':'0',
        'right':'0',
        'bottom':'0',
        'margin':'auto'
    });
```

Also give your `myBox` a position of `relative`.